# HttpClientBuilder() throwing an error in Java IDE as 'HttpsClientBuilder() has protected access in org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClient.Builder

Tags: java, eclipse, intellij-idea, selenium-webdriver, junit

Here I'm trying to execute broken link scenario in selenium webdriver and my Java IDE is throwing an error on 'HttpClientBuilder()'

Here is my code:

```
public static boolean getResponseCode(String chkurl)
{
    boolean validResponse = false;
    try {

        HttpResponse urlresp = new HttpClientBuilder().execute(new HttpGet(chkurl));
        int resp_Code = urlresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("Response Code Is : "+resp_Code);

        if ((resp_Code == 404) || (resp_Code == 505)) {
            validResponse = false;
        }
        else { 
             validResponse = true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return validResponse;

}
```

Comment: you should get rid of your if else validResponse = (!(resp_Code == 404) || (resp_Code == 505))

Answer (score 1):

The default constructor is protected try the static method create

```
HttpResponse urlresp = HttpClientBuilder.create().execute(new HttpGet(chkurl));
        int resp_Code = urlresp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Comment: I have fixed it as per your instruction but still IDE throwing following error: Error:(58, 36) java: HttpClientBuilder() has protected access in org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder                                             Error:(58, 68) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method execute(org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet)
  location: class org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder

Comment: try new HttpClientBuilder().create().build().execute(new HttpGet(chkurl)). The builder must build a client and with client execute the call

Comment: Use `HttpClientBuilder.create()` instead of `new HttpClientBuilder().create()`, `create()` is a static factory method here.